# How to create a functor that will read next value from input stream?

Tags: c++, stl, functor, istream

Something like this :

`std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&istream::get ??), cin)`. This does not seem to work for me.

EDIT:

Use :

```
vector<int> vNumbers;
generate_n(back_inserter(vNumbers), iNumCount, functor);
```

Comment: Is the `??` part of the code, or are you trying to draw attention to something?

Comment: Does it have to be a generator (?) function? Standard library has `istream_iterator` for reading the next value.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: :). No it isn't part of the code. I'm trying to ask if there is a correct function to put in there.

Comment: As Marcelo says in his answer, what you're doing doesn't (yet) make sense.  Can you give an example of how you would like to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the standard binding functions let you define nullary functions. `bind1st` binds to the first argument of a *binary* function and returns a unary function that passes its parameter as the second parameter of the bound function.

You can go outside the standard library, however, and use Boost.Bind:

```
boost::bind(&istream::get, &cin)
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::mem_fun` takes a pointer. So do

```
bind(std::mem_fun(&istream::get), &cin)
```

where

```
template <typename F, typename Res, typename Arg>
struct binder
{
    binder(F const& f, Arg const& arg) : f(f), arg(arg) {}
    Res operator()() { return f(arg); }
private:
    F f; Arg arg;
};

template <typename F, typename Arg>
binder<F, typename F::result_type, Arg> bind(F const& f, Arg const& arg)
{ return binder<F, typename F::result_type, Arg>(f, arg); }
```

You also may want to use `std::istream_iterator` with a custom / stolen `copy_n` algorithm (which sadly is not standard):

```
template <typename I, typename O>
O copy_n(size_t n, I first, I last, O result)
{
    size_t k = 0;
    while (first != last && k++ < n) *result++ = *first++;
    return result;
}
```